# How to add or remove the "open" attribute from all details tags in a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, docusaurus

I have a page with a React component that uses multiple detail/summary tags:

```
const React = require("react");

class samplePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const siteConfig = this.props.config;
    return (

        <div>
            <details>
                <summary>
                    First text detail.
                </summary>
            </details>
            <details>
                <summary>
                    Second text detail.
                </summary>
            </details>
            <details>
                <summary>
                    Third text detail.
                </summary>
            </details>

            <button onClick="OpenAll()">Open All Details.</button>
            <button onClick="CloseAll()">Close All Details.</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = samplePage;
```

I have a global `siteConfig.js` to configure my scripts:

```
scripts: [
    "js/script1.js",
    "js/script2.js",
    "js/script3.js"
],
```

With 2 functions to add or remove the "open" attribute from the above detail tags:

```
function CloseAll() {
  $("details").removeAttr("open");
}

function OpenAll() {
    $("details").attr("open", "open");
}
```

I know the 2 functions in my main script file are imported through `siteConfig.js`, as my other functions are working without issue. As can be seen from the sample page, the button tags that initiate the `OpenAll` / `CloseAll` functions are located within a `div` with the other detail tags.

I thought my method was good, but neither button produces the intended effect. I suspect this has something to do with the function scope or something about my current set-up (I'm using Docusaurus, which is kinda similar to "Create React App"). I don't think I've done anything out of the ordinary for a project like this. Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use state to set the attribute to `true` or `false`, like that. (Note that you can use hooks like here but also good old `state` and `setState`. Also you don't need `siteConfig` or the two functions defined there.

```
const React = require("react");

const samplePage = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false); 

    return (
        <div>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    First text detail.
                </summary>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Second text detail.
                </summary>
            </details>
            <details open={isOpen}>
                <summary>
                    Third text detail.
                </summary>
            </details>

            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Open All Details.</button>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Close All Details.</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = samplePage;
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the right solution, but I can't get it to work in my current set-up. Everything loads without error, but the buttons still don't function.

Comment: I made an edit to fix the erroneous `import` and `export` statements, button `id`(s) and had it rejected incorrectly by @paweł-psztyć and @moob. It was approved originally by @reuben-mallaby, who obviously understood the intent of the edit. Of course, the site doesn't allow me to respond... other than on this comment. I wrote the OP... It's the respondent who mistakenly altered the example code (yes, his solution is fine).

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a useEffect to get this to work.

```js
  const closeDetails = () => {
    console.log('click')
    setIsOpen(false)
  }
```